# Call python script (part of Anaconda package) from Java

Tags: java, python, anaconda

I am trying to trigger python code from a java scheduler. In standalone mode, we execute the python script via conda prompt, it takes arguments and returns value in JSON. How do I call this from a Java program and capture the output? Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Runtime to execute your command. Check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) as well.

Here is an example how you can use it:

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -al");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String read;

while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(read);
}

br.close();
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Java's `ProcessBuilder` to open a command line and execute your python script. Code should look like as follows (adapted to linux OS so change the command line if you're on Windows):

```
//create a command line to execute python script
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python", "scriptname.py", "param1", "param2", ...);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
//read output
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
//convert output to JSON
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Type type = new TypeToken<YourType>(){}.getType();
YourType obj = gson.fromJson(line, type);
```